# Can I configure the ROOT application to be accessed from another path in Tomcat 6?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

I have an application that is deployed as ROOT.war under `/webapps` in Tomcat.  As it is configured now, I can only access the application via http://www.example.com.  I'd like to be able to access it using http://www.example.com/myapp without having to change the fact that it is deployed as ROOT.  I have the following in my ROOT.xml:

```
<Context path="/myapp"/>
```

However, when I deploy this ROOT.xml and restart Tomcat and then I try to go to http://www.example.com/myapp, Tomcat gives me a 404.  So this tells me that changing this alone will not solve my problem.

Is it possible to configure the ROOT context to be accessed via '/myapp' in this case in Tomcat 6 without having to rename the ROOT context (e.g. without renaming webapps/ROOT.war)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rename ROOT.xml to myapp.xml with following content,

```
<Context docBase="/catalina_home/webapps/ROOT.war" />
```

By doing this, you create 2 contexts "/" and "/myapp" sharing the same WAR file.

If you just want to have one webapp, the easiest thing to do is to rename ROOT.war into myapp.war.

Comment: The <Context> you suggested did not work.  Looks like I'll need to change the name of the war file.  Thanks.

Comment: @ZZCoder Note that the webapp in this case will be deployed *twice*: one for each context path. That may be okay for the OP, but it's worth pointing out.